# Change image for a moment when user click on it Android

Tags: android

I'd like to have other button on image when operations are performing. It is this same as change image button when user click on the button.

Comment: Is the question complete??

Comment: deep in there i found question :p

Comment: Heh... Maybe I can't to describe what I have in mind....;p  When button is not used is image blue, but when I click this button Id like to change image for black for a moment :D